# Rectangles instead of letters when browsing Angular 12 app using mobile browser

Tags: angular, fonts

I have developed a website in Angular 12. When browsing using desktop browsers everything works fine. When browsing from some specific mobile browsers (e.g., Chrome 95.0.4638.74 in Android 11) some of the letters in the HTML text are missing and rectangles appear instead, as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

The font used for this heading is described in the CSS file as:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,400;1,500&display=swap');
h1, .h1{ font-size: 2.5rem; font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif; }
```

Can anyone enlighten me on the technical roots of the problem and suggest the best possible solution?

Comment: Just curious: what language has words beginning /mp/? And what's the string being displayed?

Comment: @PeterConstable it is in Greek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root issue is that a font is being used to display the text that doesn't support all of the characters in the text. When a character isn't supported by a font, the ".notdef" glyph (glyph 0) would be used, and in many fonts that looks like a rectangle as shown in your image.

It appears you're requesting the Playfair Display font from Google Fonts. According to Googles documentation of the [glyph repertoire](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Playfair+Display?query=play#glyphs) for that font, it doesn't support characters from the Greek script.

However, the image you show isn't Playfair Display at all! All the same, whatever font was selected by the browser, the rectangles appear because those characters are not supported by that font.

The more interesting questions are:

- Why wasn't Playfair Display used?
- What font *did* the browser select?
- Why didn't the browser selected another font for those characters not supported by the first font (font fallback)?

The last question in particular: for Chrome on Android, typically a Noto ("no tofu!") font would be used to avoid displaying any rectangles (aka pieces of tofu). You haven't given the actual string being displayed, so a possibility is that those aren't typical Greek characters but are some unusual Unicode characters not supported in the Noto fonts on the given device.